# why xml files are not updated after modification in odoo11

Tags: odoo-11

This is the actual code. Here i am adding filter for **domain_force**

```
<record id="sale_order_personal_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Personal Orders</field>
    <field ref="model_sale_order" name="model_id"/>
    <field name="domain_force"></field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('sales_team.group_sale_salesman'))]"/>
</record>
```

I'm trying to update xml file after adding filter for view as fallows.

```
<record id="sale_order_personal_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Personal Orders</field>
    <field ref="model_sale_order" name="model_id"/>
    <field name="domain_force">['|',('user_id','=',user.id),('user_id','=',False)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('sales_team.group_sale_salesman'))]"/>
</record>
```

I tried **updating apps, upgrading module, and restarting server**, But i didn't get solution to update view. Why its happening.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one reason xml is not updated is that you put all this code in data noupdate=1.In no update=True it didnot update our data in an external id if that id is not present in our system it will create it if id is present it didnot update its attributes.